# Join Many to One without a match

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm not sure if the wording of my question is accurate but in short, I have 4 tables I need to access data from. DEPTH, DEPTHSET, DEPTHENTRY & DEPTHSETMM. I need my output to show 1 row per DEPTHSET, per DEPTH and I'm rolling up the data from DEPTHENTRY with a LISTAGG function. My problem is that I don't get a row for every DEPTH if there is not a valid DEPTHENTRY tied to it through the DEPTHSETMM many mapping table.

I've provided sample data through with clauses and then my actual code below that along with the current output and my desired output.

```
WITH
DEPTH AS (
(SELECT 1 AS "DEPTHID", 'Group'  AS "NAME" FROM DUAL) UNION
(SELECT 2 AS "DEPTHID", 'Branch' AS "NAME" FROM DUAL) UNION
(SELECT 3 AS "DEPTHID", 'Area'   AS "NAME" FROM DUAL) UNION
(SELECT 4 AS "DEPTHID", 'Dept'   AS "NAME" FROM DUAL) UNION
(SELECT 5 AS "DEPTHID", 'Shift'  AS "NAME" FROM DUAL) UNION
(SELECT 6 AS "DEPTHID", 'Rpt'    AS "NAME" FROM DUAL) UNION
(SELECT 7 AS "DEPTHID", 'Code'   AS "NAME" FROM DUAL)
),
DEPTHSET AS (
(SELECT 3705 AS "DEPTHSETID", 'Idaho Set' AS "NAME" FROM DUAL)
),
DEPTHSETMM AS (
(SELECT 3705 AS "DEPTHSETID", 1410 AS "ENTRYID" FROM DUAL) UNION
(SELECT 3705 AS "DEPTHSETID", 1420 AS "ENTRYID" FROM DUAL) UNION
(SELECT 3705 AS "DEPTHSETID", 1421 AS "ENTRYID" FROM DUAL) UNION
(SELECT 3705 AS "DEPTHSETID", 1430 AS "ENTRYID" FROM DUAL) 
),
DEPTHENTRY AS (
(SELECT 1410 AS "ENTRYID", 'North West' AS "NAME", 1 AS "DEPTHID" FROM DUAL) UNION
(SELECT 1420 AS "ENTRYID", 'Zone 1' AS "NAME", 3 AS "DEPTHID" FROM DUAL) UNION
(SELECT 1421 AS "ENTRYID", 'Zone 2' AS "NAME", 3 AS "DEPTHID" FROM DUAL) UNION
(SELECT 1430 AS "ENTRYID", 'A' AS "NAME", 7 AS "DEPTHID" FROM DUAL) 
)
SELECT
DST.name AS "DEPTH_SET_NAME",
DEP.depthid AS "DEPTHID",
DEP.name AS "DEPTH_NAME",
LISTAGG(CAST(DEE.name AS varchar2(2000)), '; ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY DEE.name DESC) AS "ENTRY_NAME"
FROM DEPTHSETMM DMM
  LEFT OUTER JOIN DEPTHENTRY DEE ON (DMM.entryid = DEE.entryid)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN DEPTH DEP      ON (DEE.depthid = DEP.depthid)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN DEPTHSET DST        ON (DMM.depthsetid = DST.depthsetid)
GROUP BY DST.name, DEP.depthid, DEP.name
  ORDER BY DST.name, DEP.depthid
```

Current Output

```
DEPTH_SET_NAME  DEPTHID  DEPTH_NAME  ENTRY_NAME
Idaho Set       1        Group       North West
Idaho Set       3        Area        Zone 2; Zone 1
Idaho Set       7        Code        A
```

Desired Output

```
DEPTH_SET_NAME  DEPTHID  DEPTH_NAME  ENTRY_NAME
Idaho Set       1        Group       North West
Idaho Set       2        Branch      NULL
Idaho Set       3        Area        Zone 2; Zone 1
Idaho Set       4        Dept        NULL
Idaho Set       5        Shift       NULL
Idaho Set       6        Rpt         NULL
Idaho Set       7        Code        A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cross-join between `DEPTHSET` and `DEPTH`, and then outer-join to the remaining tables:

```
WITH ...
SELECT
DST.name AS "DEPTH_SET_NAME",
DEP.depthid AS "DEPTHID",
DEP.name AS "DEPTH_NAME",
LISTAGG(CAST(DEE.name AS varchar2(2000)), '; ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY DEE.name DESC) AS "ENTRY_NAME"
FROM DEPTHSET DST
CROSS JOIN DEPTH DEP
  LEFT OUTER JOIN DEPTHENTRY DEE ON (DEE.depthid = DEP.depthid)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN DEPTHSETMM DMM ON (DMM.entryid = DEE.entryid)
                                 AND (DMM.depthsetid = DST.depthsetid)
GROUP BY DST.name, DEP.depthid, DEP.name
  ORDER BY DST.name, DEP.depthid;

DEPTH_SET    DEPTHID DEPTH_ ENTRY_NAME                    
--------- ---------- ------ ------------------------------
Idaho Set          1 Group  North West                    
Idaho Set          2 Branch                               
Idaho Set          3 Area   Zone 2; Zone 1                
Idaho Set          4 Dept                                 
Idaho Set          5 Shift                                
Idaho Set          6 Rpt                                  
Idaho Set          7 Code   A
```

Notice the `AND (DMM.depthsetid = DST.depthsetid)` in the second outer join, replacing what used to be an indirect condition.